# Application Framework to integrate ASP.NET MVC and MVVM

Tags: model-view-controller, mvvm, frameworks

We have a WPF application. There are plans to extend this application in the future as well as port some of the functionality to the web.

I know that I should be using the MVVM design pattern for WPF. I would like to use ASP.NET MVC for the web application. My question is, is there an application framework that sort of integrates these 2 and makes it easier to develop WPF and ASP.NET apps side by side.

The goal is minimal code duplication.

I am looking at CSLA.NET right now. It claims support for ASP.NET MVC and MVVM apps. I am not sure how much support there is until I fully evaluate it.

Thanks,

Nachiket

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing, from a "I'm going to develop stuff and want to target Silverlight AND Web" perspective. Have you had any luck doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply not possible because MVC and MVVM are "completely" different. What you should do is put as much code into services as possible. These services can be re-used where you only have to write the usage of the service (this can be the controller or the view model). Then you keep most of the logic in the services which can be retrieved via an IoC container (or service locator).